# Xamarin Google Service Auth Missing SignInHubActivity on Manifest

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to Login with Google and i follow google steps on the https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

And i am receiving this error.

Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException has been thrown
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.estrategiamktdigital.foodsage/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I tried to insert manualy on obj/debug/android/manifest.
And did not work.

Here is the code attempt

Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException has been thrown
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.estrategiamktdigital.foodsage/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I tried to insert manualy on obj/debug/android/manifest.
And did not work.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
            .RequestEmail()
            .RequestIdToken("myrequestId") 
            .Build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .EnableAutoManage(this , this )
            .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .Build();
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);   StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, you didn't correctly add `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity` to your manifest, although you said you tried to "insert manualy on obj/debug/android/manifest".

To add this in manifest, you can open your project with VS, in the `AndroidManifest.xml` under `Properties`:

[image]

And then add this code:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" />
```

inside your `<application android:lable="...">` node.